# AJAX POST from a href class

Tags: ajax

I have a problem with my script. Why this AJAX don't do anything..
Thanks For help..

In body tag

```
<div class="share_playlist">    
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="add to playlist" class="plyshr" id="<?php echo $tracks['track_id']; ?>">
        <img src="assets/img/ico/share_icon.png" width="28">
    </a>
</div>
```

and AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(".plyshr").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
    var parent = $(this);
        //alert (data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "playlist.php",
            success: function(html)
            data:  dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
        }).done(function( msg ) {
        parent.html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

some more details

And in playlist.php

```
include 'connect.php';
session_start();
$ip=$_SESSION['id'];
if ($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $ip_sql="insert into playlist (id_user, track_id) values ('$ip','$id')";
    $list = mysql_query($ip_sql);
    if(isset ($list)){
        echo ("succes");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in your JavaScript.

Comment: Now we can see that `success: function(html)` has no body and repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

you are having a syntax error in your javascript

```
 success: function(html){
data:  dataString,
```

there should be a brace